# Is there a way to force enable USB debugging on an android phone?

Tags: android, mobile, adb, usb-debugging

**Is there a way to force enable USB debugging on an Android phone with a black, cracked, or no screen?**

My phone (Vivo y20i 2021) broke and the screen became all black and unresponsive so I removed it. I only use Scrcpy now to access and use it. I plan to factory reset my phone, but USB debugging will be disabled. I hope someone can help. Thanks!

I tried watching on YouTube but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: USB debugging can be enabled by default, but that requires changes of the used ROM, so a bootloader unlocked device (often also called "rooted").